# Snowflake stored procedure input parameter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to form a SQL construct using a stored procedure which would have email_id passed as a variable i.e., "`v_created_by`" as one of the input parameter.

My code skeleton looks like :

```
create or replace procedure testing_proc(type varchar, ..., ..., ..., v_created_by varchar)
returns varchar not null
....,
....,

begin
  wh_setup := 'CREATE OR REPLACE WAREHOUSE' || ' ' || wh_name || ' ' || 'WITH' || ' '
              || 'WAREHOUSE_SIZE = ' || v_wh_size || ' '
              ...
              ...
              || 'SCALING_POLICY= ' || 'STANDARD' || ' '
              || 'COMMENT=' || v_created_by;
  execute immediate wh_setup;
  return 'successfully created the warehouse :' || ' ' || wh_name;
end;
```

Whenever I am calling the proc like :

```
call testing_proc('STD','EDWQA','ANALYST','XSMALL','1','1',300,'somen.swain@GMAIL.COM')
```

I get the error as :

```
"Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 15 at position 2 : 
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 199 unexpected '@GMAIL.COM'. 
syntax error line 1 at position 199 unexpected '@GMAIL.COM'.
```

Reference SQL which I am trying to create via procedure is given below:

```
CREATE WAREHOUSE IF NOT EXISTS dbt_workload 
WITH    WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL' 
        WAREHOUSE_TYPE = 'STANDARD'

        SCALING_POLICY = 'STANDARD'
COMMENT = '"created for testing"';
```

Please see the `COMMENT keyword` over here where it can be used as a tag.

Any pointers on how to address this to ensure I can use this email_id and pass it with comment section would really help.

Answer (score 0):

The comment has to be wrapped with `'` as it requires string literal:

```
COMMENT = '<string_literal>'
```

Instead:

```
|| 'COMMENT=' || v_created_by;
```

to:

```
|| 'COMMENT=''' || v_created_by || ''';
```

The input should be validated/trusted before passing it to be run.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.  But still I am getting the error post changing the code  to                     || 'COMMENT= '''|| v_created_by ||'''  , this time the procedure did not get compiled and the error was "SQL compilation error: syntax error line 16 at position 10 unexpected 'successfully'. syntax error line 16 at position 23 unexpected 'created'. parse error line 18 at position 0 near '<EOF>'."

Comment: @SomenSwain Are you wrapping the code with `$$`?    `CREATE PROCEDURE ... AS $$ BEGIN .... END; $$;`

Comment: Yes.. I am wrapping it as between $$ as you have mentioned..

Comment: Hi - if you change your SP to temporarily return wh_setup, rather than execute it, you can see the statement that is actually being generated and should therefore be able to debug the issue

Comment: Ok.. thanks all for the inputs. All of this helped in debugging it and I am able to parse the value now..